# Null being passed in input box

Tags: visualforce, controller, inputtext

I have a visual force input box

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!displayDayCount}">
    X=<apex:inputText value="{!recurringTaskLPP.dayCount}" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

The class recurringTaskLpp has this for getter and setter

```
public string dayCount { get; set; }
```

Now in the controller when I try to access the input box then I get the value as null. I have made the object of the recurring task in the controller constructor and now to access it in the controller recurringTaskObject.dayCount. but it always give null. can someone tell why

Comment: can you please post the controller code along this

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
< apex:inputText value="{!dayCount}" />
```

Comment: This answer has already been deleted once.